# Is it possible to databind using an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I think that's the right terminology...

Basically, I have a repeater control, and a Linq query that retrieves some items. Ordinarily I would databind straight to the query and use Eval to populate the template with the results.

However, it doesn't come through in quite the right format - for example, if EndDate is null (it's a DateTime?) then I want to substitute it with "Present". I am using only a couple of the properties in the query result objects.

I am wondering if there's a solution like:

```
[pseudo madeup code]
var query = getResults();

List<anonymous> anonList = new List();

foreach (var q in query)
{
   string myEndDate = "";
   if (q.EndDate.HasValue) 
       { myEndDate = q.EndDate.ToString(); }
   else 
       { myEndDate = "Present"; }

   anonList.items.add(new { name=q.name, enddate=myEndDate };
}

repeater.Datasource = anonList;
```

then

```
<div><%#Eval("enddate")%></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options for declaring you result list:

1. Use a non-generic `ArrayList`, or
2. Use `Enumerable.Repeat`, ie. `var anonList = Enumerable.Repeat(new { name="", enddate=""}, 0).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you *can* bind against anonymous types but your code to generate the sequence of those types will have to change a bit:

```
repeater.DataSource
    = getResults()
        .Select(q => new {
            name = q.name,
            enddate = (q.EndDate.HasValue) 
                        ? q.EndDate.ToString() 
                        : "Present"
        });
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without all that logic being inline? It can make it pretty unreadable, especially if you are combining two strings that may be null, for example `fullname = q.user.title + q.user.firstname + q.user.lastname;` if user is null it will fail, and doing three inline checks plus combining them into one variable is pretty hideous.

Answer (score 1):

You could take Andrews sample:

```
repeater.DataSource    = getResults()
    .Select(q => new {
        name = q.name,
        enddate = (q.EndDate.HasValue)
                     ? q.EndDate.ToString()
                     : "Present"        });
```

but instead of computing the enddate inline, you call a function:

```
repeater.DataSource = getResults()
    .Select(q => new {
        name = q.name,
        enddate = GetEndDate(q)});


    private void GetEndDate(TypeOfQ q)
    {
       return (q.EndDate.HasValue) ? q.EndDate.ToString() : "Present";
    }
```

Is that what you ment??

regards,
Chris